# High pitch noise from head phone of Bootcamp partition after upgrading to Big Sur 11.5.2

Tags: mac, audio, boot-camp

Recently, I upgraded by MacBook Pro to Big Sur 11.5.2. The Mac side is working fine. On another partition where I have Windows 10 installed, the headphone is giving intolerable high pitch noise once I have some audio to play.

I tried to use the Apple Software Update and there is no updated drivers.

On the Mac side, I have

- MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)
- Processor 2.8 GHz, Quad-Core Intel Core i7
- Memory 16GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3

On the Windows side, it is Windows 10.

What can I do? I am hoping I don't have to reinstall the Windows partition.

Update: 09-15-2021
The audio issue seems to fixed itself after upgrading to Big Sur 11.6

Update: 09-24-2021
After several switching back and forth between OSX and Windows, the issue reappears again. So Big Sur 11.6 did not solve the problem.

I wonder it might have to do with the state when I shutdown OSX, here is a summary of cases I tried.

```
Bluetooth/Speaker Volume/Headset Volume -> Bootcamp side status
(On)     /(Mute)        /(Mute)         -> Noise 
(Off)    /(Mute)        /(Not Mute)     -> Noise
```